Как реализовать чат мессенджера избегая WebSockets?
Изучая тему WebSockets, зашёл в VK мессенджер и в консоли увидел, что при отправки сообщения, используется обычный HTTP, как реализовать тогда чат на HTTP, избегая WebSockets, где можно об этом почитать и больше узнать?
Не совсем понятно, как при отправки сообщения с помощью HTTP, человек на другом конце диалог также получает это сообщения, ведь REST API возвращает ответ лишь автору запроса.


Использовать поллинг или SSE. Вот можете почитать: Сравнение технологий WebSockets, Server-Sent-Events, Long-Polling, WebRTC и WebTransport

Чем вам не нравятся сокеты?

Как связано то, что отправляется HTTP запрос и WebSockets?  По-вашему что, при других способах не будет отправляться HTTP запрос?  Вы знаете что это вообще за зверь?

"как человек на другом конце диалог также получает это сообщения, ведь REST API возвращает...." --- всё смешалось кони люди...... причём тут вообще REST?  А получает другой собеседник сообщения потому, что сервер отправляет этому самому собеседнику сообщение через тот же websocket или SSE, при возникновении события на сервере, на которое он (собеседник) подписан....

@Faraday просто ТС не знает устройство сети и как в целом происходит путь от браузера до сервера, вот и придумал что-то себе в голове

На каком языке собираетесь писать чат? Так-то во многих языках есть библиотеки, которые сами автоматически выберут наиболее подходящий способ передачи данных.
